# Disable node.js app debugging in Visual Studio Code (vscode)

Tags: node.js, ide, visual-studio-code

I am working on this node.js application using Visual Studio Code IDE. Everytime I run this application, it is attaching a debugger (which takes around **2-5 seconds**) and then executing the application.

So, my issue is everytime if I modify some code (or a simple variable name) and execute the program, it takes this much time to see the output even though I haven't set any breakpoints.

Need help in disabling the debugger in Visual Studio Code IDE for node applications development. I can't find anything helpful on net :( .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is `workbench.action.debug.run` which is bound to `cmd+f5` / `ctrl+f5` by default.

You can find it in the command palette under the name "Debug: Start without Debugging"

Comment: I press `F5` to start the application which, of course, triggers the 'start of debug panel'. Is there no way to modify `launch.json` and achieve my aim?

Comment: Ok, you got me, I search around and found https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/2780 where this "feature" is discussed. Its useful, but still sounds kinda wrong to "debug without debugging". Updated my answer ;)

Comment: Is there any option to directly execute instead of debug from `launch.json`?

Comment: That's what the command does, the debugger skips what it would normally do and "node --nolazy app.js" gets started in the background, no debugger gets attached. You still need the setup via launch.json though, if that is what you ask.

Comment: You rock. I have now interchanged the `cmf+f5` with 'f5'. Now I can execute my node program hassle free and faster. Thanks. You saved my `(2 to 5 seconds) * ∞` time. :)

Answer (score 10):

Inside the VsCode terminal, I've switched the terminal to `zsh` instead of the `JS Debug Console` and it fixed it:

[Screenshot of the terminal's dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmOQT.png)

Answer (score 5):

You can just switch from "Javascript Debug Terminal" to "powershell" (command terminal). it doesn't attach the debugger again

[image: Screenshot of the terminal]

Answer (score 3):

consider passing the option below on `settings.json`

```json
"debug.javascript.autoAttachFilter": "onlyWithFlag"
```

with this option, you will always need to pass ---inspect option to start debugging mode. otherwise, it will always start normal running mode.